# about measuring lemma 

Tags: gr.group-theory

I wonder if you explain that why Chermak and Delgado named it in their article by measuring lemma? Is the measuring lemma caused the measure on finite groups?

A. Chermak, A. L. Delgado, A measuring argument for finite groups, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.
107 (1989), 907-914.

measuring lemma:let $ ‎A,B‎ ‎\in‎ ‎\alpha‎\mathcal{M}‎ $ and assume that either$ ‎A‎\cap B‎‎ ‎\neq ‎1‎ $‎‏ ‎ 
or that $ ‎m‎_{‎\alpha‎}‎‎‎ ‎\geq‎ ‎\vert H ‎\vert‎ $‎ .

Then ‎‎‎$ ‎‎AB=BA‎ \in‎  ‎\alpha‎\mathcal{M} $‎ and  $ C_{H} ( A \cap B ) = C_{H} (A) C_{H}(B) $
 Further, if $  A \cap B \neq 1$ then $ A \cap B \in   \alpha‎\mathcal{M} $ .
we have the following notation:
Let $G$ be finite group acting on a finite group $H$, and let 
$  S^{*} (G) = $  $\brace  all\ non-trivial\ subgroups\ of\ G  $

$  ‎m‎_{‎\alpha‎} $

$=  m‎_{‎\alpha‎} ( G,H ) $

$ = ‎‎ \max  ‎\lbrace $ ‎‎‎$  ‎\vert  ‎A‎ ‎ \vert‎^{‎\alpha‎}‎$ $ \vert C‎_{H}(A)‎‎ ‎\vert‎^{‎\alpha‎} $ $  \ \ \  ‎‎\vert‎  \ $ $ \ \ \ A ‎‎\in S‎^{‎\ast‎‎}(G)$ $‎\rbrace ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎$‎ ;

$ ‎\alpha‎\mathcal{M}$

$=‎\alpha‎\mathcal{M}(G,H)$

$=‎\lbrace $ $ A ‎‎\in$  $ S‎^{‎\*‎‎}(G) $ $     ‎‎\vert  $   $   ‎‎ ‎\vert ‎A‎ ‎\vert‎^{‎\alpha‎}‎ $   $ \vert C‎_{H}(A)‎‎ ‎\vert‎^{‎\alpha‎}    $

$ =m‎_{‎\alpha‎}  ‎\rbrace ‎.‎$‎‎

$ ‎C‎_{H}(A)$

$=fix‎_{H}(A)$

$ =‎\lbrace $  $ h‎ \in ‎H $  ‎ $ ‎\vert $    $ h‎^{a}=h  $  ‎ ‎‎ $\forall ‎‎a ‎\in A$    $‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎\rbrace‎ $‎

Where   $ h‎^{a}  $  denotes the action of $a$ on $ h $.

Best Regards

Comment: Pls rephrase the lemma.

Comment: Yes, please give the statement of the lemma in your question.  You're asking for help, so it's a good idea to make it easy for someone to help you.

Comment: okay now the notation has to specified;-)